# HTTP 500 internal error in jdeveloper

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jdeveloper

I'm working on an assignment. An online order system using EJB 3.0. im using jDeveloper 10 and oracle 10g for the database. i have coded around 20%, now i need to check the system that i have developed so far. so when i run the web client it does not show me any error and it runs successfully. but when the browser tries to open the page it says. HTTP 500 internal error on the browser. My jsp page is under web directory anyway. output pic is attached. 
how could solve this issue?

Comment: So you've completed 20% of your application and nothing works at all? You must provide more details, e.g. exception stacktraces or code!

Comment: When you get a 500 internal server error, look at the Weblogic console **shown within JDeveloper** There will be a clear log with error stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contributions. 
I guess it was something wrong with my jdeveloper 10. i installed the jdeveloper 11 n i started running on it. the project started to run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are there any log files on your web server ?
2. Put in your code some statement to log to file what is doing.
3. Use a browser with developer support, like Firefox with Firebug, and watch the HTTP transactions.
4. Which other conditions change between web client and browser mode ?

Answer (score 0):

> how could solve this issue?

Look at the log files in your EJB server.  There will probably be an entry or entries  corresponding to your browser's attempting to fetch the page that resulted in the 500 error.  They should give some information about what is happening, and may even give you a stack trace.  Also check the SEVERE / ERROR / WARNING entries prior to the event.

If that doesn't give you an answer, you need to investigate what is different about the requests when they come from your web client versus from your browser.  If your EJB implementation has a way to capture the incoming request headers, use that.  Otherwise, you could use wireshark or tcpdump to capture them.